# How do i add data to arraylist by a particular index of array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, k-means

[Click here for pic of Arraylists in an array Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN1Ty.jpg)

Is it possible to add arraylists into array? and I want to insert data into a particular index no of arrray. for example, into arraylist of array[3]. If it isnt possible, how to i solve in another way? I am writing kmeans clustering in java. This is the adding element to particular cluster.

Comment: ArrayList is a known data structure. But what do you mean by 'array'? a regular one, or a composite object of some sort?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear - are you asking if you can add an item to an array list on a specific index?  or are you asking if you can add a whole  array list into another array list on a given index?

Comment: Maybe a hashmap of arraylist would do the trick?

Comment: I want to add an item to an array list on a specific index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but if what you need is to create an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`'s, meaning a parent `ArrayList` with other `ArrayList`'s as elements you could use generic types, also known as templates.

To declare your parent array you can do something like this, assuming your inner child arrays will contain int values:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayOfarrays = new ArrayList<>();
```

In order to access data from one of the inner child arrays you can do something like this:

```
int value = arrayOfarrays.get(3).get(0);
```

That line would return the value at index 0 from the child array at index 3.
In order to add child arrays you would need to use the `add` method:

```
ArrayList<Integer> childArray = new ArrayList<>();
arrayOfarrays.add(childArray); //adds the given array at the last position
arrayOfarrays.add(1, childArray); //adds the given array at index 1
```

Comment: how about If i would like to add an item at Index 1 of array?

Comment: then you would have to use the same logic of extraction but using the `add()` method.

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> childArray = new ArrayList<>();
arrayOfarrays.add(childArray); //add the given array at the last position
arrayOfarrays.add(1, childArray);//add  the given array at the index 1

Comment: This is adding the whole arraylist, right? how about if i would like to add each item to ChildArray of arrayOfarrays[1]?

Comment: Yes, iif you want to insert a new value to one of the child arrays you first need to `get()` the desired array and then `add()` the desired item. You can acomplish that by doing:
`arrayOfArrays.get(1).add(value)` //add the given value at the end of the child list at index 1, you may also use an index based insertion

You could even loop any of the child arrays if you need it as well:

`ArrayList<Integer> childArrayWithData = arrayOfarrays.get(1);
 for( ... ) //then you can loop the child array`  

In order to **update** a value you will have to use the `set()` method instead of `add()`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the ArrayList must contain the same number of elements as the length of the array since you cannot change the length of an array once its instantiated. What you can do is build an array using the number of terms in the ArrayList.

For Example:

```
List<Integers> list = new ArrayList<Integers>(); 
int[] arr = new int[list.size()];
```

then to add elements of ArrayList into array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    arr[i] = list.get(i);
}
```